# Which arrow should be there in dfd?

Tags: dataflow

Not sure whether this is the right place to ask such a question. But I trust this has an answer over here.

I am supposed to make a `Data Flow Diagram` and am confused whether is it right to use straight arrows instead of curved ones?

[image: Here is the sample image]

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Style matters in Yourdan notation and can be used by the analyst to provide additional meaning to the DFDs. The size and shape of bubbles are up to the diagram creator and their client. Curved or straight arrows can be used. A diagram looks neater with one or the other but not both in the same process. There is no excuse for hand-drawn diagrams today except during a white-boarding stage.

The analyst may choose to name the processes for the role that performs them, as well as use colors to differentiate the types of entities or flows in the diagrams.  With all of these style options the DFDs can provide as much or as little detail as is needed to appropriately represent the process for the given audience.